# ¿Por qué Throwable.printStackTrace() debe ser removido?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

En sentencias try / catch, en desarrollo, en ocasiones uso el método **printStackTrace()** de la siguiente manera:

```
try {
    // código
    // ...
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // traza de error
}
```

Netbeans 8.2, por defecto, recomienda su eliminación:

> Throwable.printStackTrace() should be removed

Permite eliminarlo sin más, sin dar una alternativa con lo que el error se silencia, ¿porqué ocurre esto?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469316/why-is-exception-printstacktrace-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 3):

Es un consejo de buen uso. 
Realmente no pasa nada por ponerlo, pero una manera mas correcta seria, por ejemplo usar un Logger para mostrar el error en el lugar adecuado.
Si dejas esa printStackTrace, en un aplicacion que esta en producción, la salida sera redirigida a la salida estandar de errores, la cual a menudo no vera nadie, con lo cual, se estara produciendo un error que nadie vera, pero que probablemente hara que el programa no funcione correctamente.